# Windows 8.1 full disc encryption

Tags: encryption, windows-8

I have a zenbook ux302 that I want to do a full disc encryption on.
I had no problem using bitlocker on my stationary computer, but the zenbook doesn't seem to have that functionality?
I have the standard windows 8.1 (no Pro or something like that).

When I press the pc info tab, I have no encryption there either.

Can I use bitlocker? 
Is there some other smooth program I can use otherwise?

I read that windows 8.1 is by default encrypted (sometimes?) 
I guess my computer is not.
All advice's are appreciated.

Comment: If you're having a problem using a Windows feature, you'll probably find Super User a better place for this question. That being said, your processor may be missing a TPM, you'll have a hard time working around this without Pro (because regular 8.1 doesn't have gpedit).

Comment: [Bitlocker Drive Encryption](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/protect-files-bitlocker-drive-encryption#1TC=windows-8) is only available on Windows 8.1 Pro and Enterprise editions.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that my response is mostly from my personal notes and therefore has some snippets that people other than myself have written.

Aside from BitLocker, as of Windows 8.1, pervasive device encryption is enabled by default when using a Microsoft account.  Device encryption previously found on Windows RT and Windows Phone 8 is now available in all editions of Windows. It is enabled out of the box and can be configured with additional BitLocker protection and management capability on Windows 8.1 Pro and Windows 8.1 Enterprise. Consumer devices are automatically encrypted and protected when using a Microsoft account.

Data on any Windows connected standby device is automatically protected (encrypted) with device encryption. Organizations that need to manage encryption can easily add additional BitLocker protection options and manageability to these devices.  Additional security notes for Windows 8.1 can be found [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/dn140266.aspx), and device encryption details can be found here - [source1](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn306081.aspx#BKMK_Encryption) and [source2](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/using-device-encryption).  A backup of your key (If you are not AD-joined) is sent to Microsoft [here](https://skydrive.live.com/recoverykey).  Some requirements are:

- Secure Boot support, which requires both an x64 edition of Windows 8.1 and not your old fashioned 32 bit version, and UEFI bootware instead of a BIOS.
- A Trusted Platform Module, or TPM, chip which has been standard issue on most business and corporate oriented laptops since 2008. TPM chips are typically not used on inexpensive laptops marketed primarily toward consumer channels, although this will likely change as a result of the Windows 8.1 device specifications.
- Support for connected standby (aka InstantGo), which is the mode where almost all of the device is put into extremely low power mode except the network device, which maintains a connection and wakes up every so often to receive push notifications, e-mails, and other network information. Connected standby requires a solid state drive and not spinning media, soldered memory that does not come in pluggable SIMMS or DIMMS, and network cards compatible with NDIS 6.30.

If you do not have TPM, you are able to use a USB drive.  Details [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/6229/how-to-use-bitlocker-on-drives-without-tpm/).

There are other free options for full disk encryption on Windows 8.1 if you do not have 8.1 Pro or Enterprise, such as [DiskCryptor](https://diskcryptor.net/wiki/Main_Page) (but beware that [I do not believe it currently supports GPT](https://diskcryptor.net/forum/index.php?topic=4680.0))